# Youtube playlist in Html and css

Tags: html, css

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}

body {
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    height: auto;
    line-height: 1;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding: 2rem;
    width: 100%;
}

.video {
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 4.1%;
    padding-bottom: 51.95%;
    height: 0;
}

.video iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 0;
}

.video-gallery {
    margin-top: 3em;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

.video-gallery .video {
    animation: 1200ms fadeOut ease;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-row-start: 1;
    grid-row-end: 7;
    max-height: 19.5em;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 300ms ease;
}

.video-gallery input[type="radio"] {
    font-size: 0;
    height: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: fixed;
    width: 0;
}

.video-gallery input {
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-row-start: 1;
}

.video-gallery label {
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 1.25em;
    font-weight: 400;
    grid-column-start: 2;
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 1rem 0 1rem 3rem;
    position: relative;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
}

.video-gallery label:last-of-type {
    border: 0 none;
}

.video-gallery input[type="radio"]:checked+label {
    color: #E41F35 !important;
}

.video-gallery input[type="radio"]:checked+label:before {
    content: "▶";
    left: 0;
    top: 12px;
    position: absolute;
}

.grid-row {
    display: block;
    height: 56vw;
    max-height: 19.5em;
    position: relative;
}

.grid-row label {
    left: calc(50% + 16px);
    position: relative;
    width: calc(50% - 16px);
}

.grid-row .video {
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 0;
}

.grid-row:after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: table;
}

#video-1:checked~.video-1,
#video-2:checked~.video-2,
#video-3:checked~.video-3,
#video-4:checked~.video-4,
#video-5:checked~.video-5,
#video-6:checked~.video-6 {
    animation: 1200ms fadeIn ease;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
    opacity: 1;
    width: 50%;
}

@keyframes fadeOut {
    0% {
        display: block;
        height: 56vw;
        opacity: 1;
        width: 50%;
    }
    25% {
        display: block;
        height: 56vw;
        opacity: 1;
        width: 50%;
    }
    49% {
        display: block;
        height: 56vw;
        opacity: 0;
        width: 50%;
    }
    50% {
        display: none;
        height: 0;
        opacity: 0;
        width: 0;
    }
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        width: 0;
    }
    49% {
        display: none;
        height: 0;
        opacity: 0;
        width: 0;
    }
    50% {
        display: block;
        height: 56vw;
        opacity: 0;
        width: 50%;
    }
    100% {
        display: block;
        height: 56vw;
        opacity: 1;
        width: 50%;
    }
}

@supports (display: grid) {
    @keyframes fadeOut {
        0% {
            display: block;
            height: 56vw;
            opacity: 1;
            width: 100%;
        }
        25% {
            display: block;
            height: 56vw;
            opacity: 1;
            width: 100%;
        }
        49% {
            display: block;
            height: 56vw;
            opacity: 0;
            width: 100%;
        }
        50% {
            display: none;
            height: 0;
            opacity: 0;
            width: 0;
        }
    }
    @keyframes fadeIn {
        0% {
            opacity: 0;
            width: 0;
        }
        49% {
            display: none;
            height: 0;
            opacity: 0;
            width: 0;
        }
        50% {
            display: block;
            height: 56vw;
            opacity: 0;
            width: 100%;
        }
        100% {
            display: block;
            height: 56vw;
            opacity: 1;
            width: 100%;
        }
    }
}

.grid-row {
    align-items: start;
    display: grid;
    grid-column-gap: 16px;
    grid-row-gap: 0;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    width: 100%;
}

.grid-row label {
    left: auto;
    width: 100%;
}

.grid-row .video {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .video-gallery {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        height: auto;
        max-height: none;
    }
    .video-gallery label {
        left: auto;
        order: 2;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .video-gallery .video {
        order: 1;
        padding-top: 4.1%;
        padding-bottom: 51.95%;
        position: relative;
        top: auto;
        width: 100%;
    }
    #video-1:checked~.video-1,
    #video-2:checked~.video-2,
    #video-3:checked~.video-3,
    #video-4:checked~.video-4,
    #video-5:checked~.video-5,
    #video-6:checked~.video-6 {
        width: 100%;
    }
    @keyframes fadeOut {
        0% {
            display: block;
            height: 56vw;
            opacity: 1;
        }
        25% {
            display: block;
            height: 56vw;
            opacity: 1;
        }
        49% {
            display: block;
            height: 56vw;
            opacity: 0;
        }
        50% {
            display: none;
            height: 0;
            opacity: 0;
        }
    }
    @keyframes fadeIn {
        0% {
            opacity: 0;
        }
        49% {
            display: none;
            height: 0;
            opacity: 0;
        }
        50% {
            display: block;
            height: 56vw;
            opacity: 0;
        }
        100% {
            display: block;
            height: 56vw;
            opacity: 1;
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="1.css">

<body>
    <div class="grid-row reverse video-gallery">
        <input type="radio" value="1" name="video-list" id="video-1" checked="checked" /><label for="video-1">Option 1</label>
        <input type="radio" value="2" name="video-list" id="video-2" /><label for="video-2">Option 2</label>
        <input type="radio" value="3" name="video-list" id="video-3" /><label for="video-3">Option 3</label>
        <input type="radio" value="4" name="video-list" id="video-4" /><label for="video-4">Option 4</label>
        <input type="radio" value="5" name="video-list" id="video-5" /><label for="video-5">Option 5</label>
        <input type="radio" value="6" name="video-list" id="video-6" /><label for="video-6">Option 6</label>

        <!-- videos -->
        <div class="video video-1">
            <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ROqDTIxRX0Y" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>

        <div class="video video-2">
            <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/9iGoDNlKY-g" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>

        <div class="video video-3">
            <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/l70UhhNalqA" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>

        <div class="video video-4">
            <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/XDrB5c4-c9Y" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>

        <div class="video video-5">
            <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/UXP307MGQzs" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>

        <div class="video video-6">
            <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/0kY0Q5hdjDI" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
        <!-- videos -->
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I created this video player by some online code but I want know how to set options below and video above like video player is above and options to select is below video player. If I use this code in mobile it will work fine or need to add any code ,that it will be responsive or need to add anything?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

use bootstrap to make it responsive
https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/